# A rectangle R is the union of a zero set and countably many disjoint discs

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that a rectangle R is the union of a zero set and countably many disjoint discs.

This question is from Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis, page $424$ question $39.b$.

Any hint on proving this statement? I really do not know where to start.

Thanks!

I think in the book rectangle $R$ means $(a,b) \times (c,d)$

Comment: So that others can give you appropriate help, it would be useful for you to describe the content of the section in which this problem appears.

Comment: I just give some illustrations, not proof. First we can understand this theorem for one dimensional interval. Just recall the construction of Cantor set. Now you question is in two dimension, we can consider some-like constructions of products  of Cantor set.

Comment: I'm guessing that these "disjoint disks" look something like this: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket (but with a square instead of a circle). (To see that there's a countable amount of circles there, notice that each circle contains at least one rational point, so the amount of circles is $\le$ the amount of rational points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Vitali covering theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma#Vitali_covering_theorem)